# M_PI is converted to a string when addObject used

Tags: objective-c

Why does this add M_PI as a string "3.141593" to an NSMutableArray? How can I add M_PI as a float to the array?

```
- (void)pushOperand:(float)operand
{
    [self.operandStack addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:operand]];
}

[self pushOperand:M_PI];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, you can't store a float directly in an `NSMutableArray`. Your code is already inserting the value as an instance of `NSNumber`, however, and this is what you want. Later, when you pull the object back out of the array, you can restore it to a POD type with something like this:

```
double value = 0;

id topOfStack = [stack popOperand];

if ([topOfStack isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) 
    result = [topOfStack doubleValue];
```

Kudos, by the way, for doing the Stanford iOS course :-)

Answer (score 0):

M_PI converts to a NSObject, which is an object but not a string.

Comment: What converts it to an NSObject? Isn't M_PI just a constant float? So are you saying floats are converted to objects with whatever is converting?

Comment: I haven't understood this answer, if he means that M_PI is an object that's wrong.

Comment: [NSNumber numberWithFloat:operand] converts the float into NSNumber, which inherits from NSObject. Thats why you can dump the object via NSLog("%@", ...) as a NSObject and looks like a string.

Answer (score 0):

You can not add POD types to the `NSMutableArray`, only NSObject's and descendants. That's because `retain` message is sent to the object when you're adding it and `release` when removed. If you want to use float as is then you should consider smth. like `std::vector<float>`.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing to a float is a NSNumber:

```
NSNumber* mpi= @(M_PI);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine.  What makes you think it's an NSString when added to your array?